# Window width and resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to calculate the number of icons e.g. 50px depending on the width of the window for a menu.
So I started with:

```
$(window).width();
```

While loading the page with document ready function the width will be given. OK!

Now I would calculate the right amount of icons while resize the window.

`$(window).resize(function() {
  //resize just happened, pixels changed
});`

Tasks

1. Initial width of the window -> if user is not resizing the window
2. Variable width of the window -> if user is resizing the window

Each task is running but i don´t get it together.

Can u help me  --> THX!!

How can i calculate the number of icons with an initial width of the window and while resizing the window?

My Start:

```
var activeItemcount; 

                checkWidth();
                $(window).resize(checkWidth);

                   function checkWidth() {
                        windowSize = $(window).width();
                      //   console.log(windowSize); 

                        var activeItemWidth = '100';                            // width of the icons
                        var maxWidth = windowSize;                              // max div width on screen 
                        activeItemcount = maxWidth / activeItemWidth;           // max icon with actual screen width
                        activeItemcount = Math.round(activeItemcount) -1;       // calculation
                           console.log(activeItemcount);


                   var i = '0'; 

                     $('.platform-view').each(function(){
                            if(i < activeItemcount ){
                            $(this).wrapAll('<div class="iconview-1"  />');
                            i++;
                            }else{  
                                $(this).wrapAll('<div class="iconview-2" />');

                            }




                    });


                   };
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: If you need a personal programmer, this is **NOT** the right place to look for one.

Comment: To add to what Joseph has said, post the code that you have tried and what is the place you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your calculation into its own function:

```
function calculateIcons()
{
    var viewport = { width: $(window).width(), height: $(window).height() };
    // Do cool things with viewport.width
}
```

And then you can simply bind this function to the DOMReady and `resize` functions in jQuery as follows:

```
$(calculateIcons);
$(window).resize(calculateIcons);
```

Comment: Pretty close! If i write console.log in the calculateIcons function it is exactly what i want. How do i get the variable out of the function accessible.

Comment: Why would you need it outside of the function? Which variable do you want outside of the function?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get you clearly.
but this code will return the variable width of the windows while resizing.

Jquery:
$(window).resize(function() {

```
$('#log').append('<div>'+$(window).width()+'</div>');
```

});

HTML:

Example:
[A sample of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/8dHsR/)

Comment: Using the window resize the initial width is 0 or null. If the user is not resizing the window no icons will be shown. OR?